# Updating record changes the value from primary key to other column

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to update the data in a table using some TextBoxes and DropDowns.

Before updating the table I am showing the preview in `GridView` but when updating the data, the value of a particular column changes from the passed value i.e. primary key to the the `Name` in the table.

**Class.cs**

```
public int Update()
{
    try
    {
        int result = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", 12354);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", 1473);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", "some_text");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param4", 28);//Id from DDL
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param5", 25);//Id from DDL

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            _TransItem.TableName = "TransItems";
            _TransItem.WriteXml(sw);
            XML = sw.ToString();
        }

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransItems", XML);

        con.Open();
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cls_WriteErrorLog.Write_Error_To_File(ex.ToString());
        return -1;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have a button in `GridView` to update the record.

**Form.aspx.cs**

```
protected void GdMaster_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "CmdEdit")
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
            //some code

            ddl1.SelectedValue = ddlSaakh2.SelectedValue = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId1")).Text == "0" || ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId1")).Text == "Select" ? "" : ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId1")).Text;

            //remaining code
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dt_GridItems = new DataTable();
        dt_GridItems.Columns.Add("Field1");
        dt_GridItems.Columns.Add("Field2");
        dt_GridItems.Columns.Add("Field3");
        dt_GridItems.Columns.Add("Field4");
        dt_GridItems.Columns.Add("Field5");

        for (int i = 0; i < GdMaster.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field1"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdField1")).Text;
            dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field2"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdField2")).Text;
            dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field3"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdField3")).Text;
            dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field4"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId1")).Text;
            dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field5"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId2")).Text;
        }

        Class class = new Class();
        int i = class.Update();
    }
}
```

When it reaches in the `Update()` the `Parameters` are as shown in the code above. But the time data is entered, the value passed to the `@Param4` is the name value of that primary key in the table using `StringWriter`.

How can I enter the primary key in place of name?

Comment: because your are doing dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field4"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId1")). I guess you should be doing dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field4"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId4")) and dt_GridItems.Rows[i]["Field5"] = ((Label)GdMaster.Rows[i].FindControl("GdDdlId5")).Text;

Comment: `Field5` is another control sir. `GdDdlId1` should pass the some `int` PK like 64. Instead it is passing the `name` in the row where PK = 64.